# Corner radius getting distorted in stack view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button in viewDidLayoutSubviews as follows

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
    self.buttonOne.layer.cornerRadius = self.buttonOne.frame.size.height/2.0
    self.buttonOne.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.buttonOne.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.buttonOne.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

I am getting a distorted circle. How do I fix this?. Thanks

Comment: Can you show comparison screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies elsewhere. Most likely you have other code or constraints that later come along and stretch the button, and since the layer is a cached drawing, it is stretched.

We *know* the problem lies elsewhere, because if we simply run the code you gave, and no more, we get a circular button:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention, it was in stack view and was able to fix it. Appreciate your answer and I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, by giving equal width and height to the button in stack view as follows,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.buttonOne.frame.size = CGSize(width:60,height:60)
        self.buttonOne.layer.cornerRadius = self.buttonOne.frame.size.height/2.0
        self.buttonOne.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.buttonOne.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.buttonOne.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```